# Pandas division of 2 Groupbys from 1 dataframe : unsupported operand type(

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I'm new to pandas and I'm trying to mimic Excel.
**So I want to:**

**1. Create a new column WA - which will be one SUMIF divided by Another.**

In pandas I have tried:

```
df['WA']= df.groupby('Coin')['Price Paid (USDT)']/ df.groupby('Coin')['Amt Coin']
```

| Coin | Coin Price (USDT) | Amt Coin | Price Paid (USDT) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BTC | 42600.0 | 0.00117 | 49.842 |
| BTC | 42600.0 | 0.00117 | 49.842 |
| ETH | 4600.0 | 0.00117 | 49.842 |

But I get the following error...

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'SeriesGroupBy' and
> 'SeriesGroupBy'

SO in Excel it would be

> =SUMIF(COIN, "BTC" or A2, Price Paid)/(SUMIF(COIN, "BTC"orA2,
> Amt Coin))

**Expected format**

| Coin | Coin Price (USDT) | Amt Coin | Price Paid (USDT) | VWAP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BTC | 42600.0 | 0.00117 | 49.842 | 41300 |
| BTC | 40000.0 | 0.00117 | 49.842 | 41300 |
| ETH | 4600.0 | 0.00117 | 49.842 | 4600 |

Comment: Can you please edit your question and put there expected result?

Comment: Hi @AndrejKesely all done! Thanks so much for helping with the formatting.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, you want to compute the weighted-average of `Price Paid (USDT)`/`Amt Coin`, by each coin.

You can do:

1. Sum the total `Price Paid (USDT)` and `Amt Coin` of each coin:

```
    grp_wa = df.groupby('Coin').agg({'Price Paid (USDT)': 'sum', 'Amt Coin': 'sum'})
```

2. Then compute the `VWAP`:

```
    grp_wa['VWAP'] = grp_wa['Price Paid (USDT)'] / grp_wa['Amt Coin']
```

You should have a table (`GroupByObject`) of each coin's `VWAP` in one row. Feel free to join it back to the original `df`.

*note: I have not fully tested the code, but should be on the right track.*